# CXF Version of camel-cxf dependency

Tags: camel-cxf

How I get the CXF version used on the follwowing maven dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-cxf</artifactId>
    <version>2.16.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it using maven dependences by click on the camel-cxf dependency in my project to open the camel-cxf pom then switched to 'Effective POM'. There you can search for cxf-core dependency and get the version.